# Double periodic function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, periodic-functions

Given $T>0$, assume that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ is smooth and not constant and $aT$-periodic and $bT$-periodic for some $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. I wonder what can be said about $a$ and $b$? Also, references where I could find the answer of this question are welcome!

Thank in advance.

Comment: Unless $aT/bT = a/b$ is rational (assuming $a, b\not = 0$), $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combinations of $aT$ and $bT$ are dense in $\mathbb{R}$, and so $f$ is constant.

Comment: If $a/b$ is irrational, one can extend $\{aT, bT\}$ to a Hamel basis of $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$, and  construct a discontinuous counterexample, as with  the standard discontinuous solutions to Cauchy's functional equation.

Comment: So, the thing I can say is $a/b\in\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Nothing at all can be said without additional hypotheses.

Comment: $f$ is smooth. Sorry i didnt say. I 'm going to edit